# Android 11 / API 30 - Open YouTube link

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube, android-11

I currently struggle to have YouTube links to be opened in the browser or the YouTube app.
I am aware of the new [Package visibility in Android 11](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9) and implemented it this way.

*MyClass.java$myMethod*

```
String ytLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hp_Eg8NMfT0"
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(ytLink)); 
if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {  
  context.startActivity(intent); 
}
```

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<manifest>
  <queries>
    <intent>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
  </queries> 
</manifest>
```

However the `intent.resolveActivity` returns `null`... Every other link I've tried returns a `ComponentName` so the `Intent` can be started...
Do you have any clue?

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 9):

Yet another option would be to add the host to the queries list in the manifest:

```
<queries>    
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data  android:scheme="https" android:host="youtube.com" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

It seems that the simple approach with just the scheme fails as the Youtube app not only filters for the scheme of the request but (for obvious reasons) also for the specific host.

BTW: When I tested, both "youtube.com" and "youtu.be" worked equally on both kinds of links. I still threw in both in my app to be safe.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to put `action` and `data`  to `intent-filter` of Activity in Manifests

Such as

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data android:scheme="https" />
</intent-filter>
```

You can check the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common)

Comment: Hi, excuse me if I'm wrong but Intent filters are used to declare what an activity, service or receiver of my app can handle and open?
What I try to do is to open a YouTube URL from my app to the Browser app or the YouTube one if installed, not open it in my app ;)
It works well for any URL (newspaper, dailymotion, etc.) which launches the Browser app but for YouTube, no app nor activity is found to handle it whereas we can browse to youtube.com with the browser... Maybe a new limitation made by Google?

Comment: Sorry, you need to use category default instead of browsable to open Youtube app, just replace it with `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`. I have the same problem when start email intent on Android 11 just like you, I read the docs and followed it, and it works fine with zero explanation from new docs. Maybe they just update new docs without any helpful information.

Comment: I finally ended up adding a category ```CATEGORY_BROWSABLE``` to the Intent and it correctly opens the browser for a YouTube URL :) Your speech about ```category``` and a good night has made me rethink about it and scan the [documentation][1].

[1]: https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#java

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a `category` `CATEGORY_BROWSABLE` to the Intent to allow the browser to be one of the app to handle the YouTube URL.
You could also play with the flags `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_NON_BROWSER` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REQUIRE_DEFAULT` as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/use-cases#java) to open it in the YouTube app also but my main issue was that no activity was found so open in browser was an option ;)